# All methods in the `ElasticsearchRepository` are deprecated. What should do I use?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this query:

```
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(multiMatchQuery(searchPattern)
                        .field("fullName")
                        .field("npi")
                        .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BEST_FIELDS))
                .build();
```

How can I run it? All methods in the `ElasticsearchRepository` are deprecated:

```
public interface ElasticsearchRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    default <S extends T> S index(S entity) {
        return this.save(entity);
    }

    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    <S extends T> S indexWithoutRefresh(S var1);

    /** @deprecated */
    Iterable<T> search(QueryBuilder var1);

    /** @deprecated */
    Page<T> search(QueryBuilder var1, Pageable var2);

    /** @deprecated */
    Page<T> search(Query var1);

    Page<T> searchSimilar(T var1, @Nullable String[] var2, Pageable var3);

    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    void refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc for the deprecated methods states that you should

- either define the queries by using the standard method name derivation like *findByName*
- or use the `@Query` annotation wit a query string
- or don not use the repository interface but the `ElasticsearchOperations` to pass your custom `Query` derived queries.

We deprecated the methods from the repository interface that use the `Query`classes. Not only in Spring Data Elasticsearch, but we do not intorduce them in other modules as well; see the [comment on this Spring Data Mongo issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2610?focusedCommentId=191467&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-191467) for more information.

Comment: Ok. I need to get this query:`"fields" : [
            "fullName^1.0",
            "npi^1.0"
          ],`
How can do it with `@Query` annotation or `ElasticsearchOperations` ?

Comment: In ElasticsearchOperations Almost all methods are deprecated too. I didn't find examples(only old examples about NativeSearchQuery)

Comment: `ElasticsearchOperations`has `search` methods that take a `Query` as parameter. Which methods in`ElasticsearchOperations` are deprecated?

Comment: `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations` doesn't have `search` method. I do not understand what class you suggest

Comment: `ElasticsearchOperations` extends `SearchOperations` and therefore has this method: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/b17999f8fa86e938c175b958c46f85b41acd79ed/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/SearchOperations.java#L332-L340. So you let inject an `ElasticsearchOperations` object and use it's `search`method.